# CS50 Problem Set 2: Substitution (Need Help)

Tags: cs50

Im facing some issue here. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

**This is the check50 result:**

:) substitution.c exists

:) substitution.c compiles

:( encrypts "A" as "Z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key
expected "ciphertext: Z...", not ""

:( encrypts "a" as "z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key
expected "ciphertext: z...", not ""

:( encrypts "ABC" as "NJQ" using NJQSUYBRXMOPFTHZVAWCGILKED as key
expected "ciphertext: NJ...", not ""

:( encrypts "XyZ" as "KeD" using NJQSUYBRXMOPFTHZVAWCGILKED as key
expected "ciphertext: Ke...", not ""

:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using YUKFRNLBAVMWZTEOGXHCIPJSQD as key
expected "ciphertext: Cb...", not ""

:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using yukfrnlbavmwzteogxhcipjsqd as key
expected "ciphertext: Cb...", not ""

:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using YUKFRNLBAVMWZteogxhcipjsqd as key
expected "ciphertext: Cb...", not ""

:( encrypts all alphabetic characters using DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM as key
expected "ciphertext: Rq...", not ""

:( does not encrypt non-alphabetical characters using DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM as key
expected "ciphertext: Yq...", not ""

:) handles lack of key

:) handles too many arguments

:) handles invalid key length

:) handles invalid characters in key

:) handles duplicate characters in key

:) handles multiple duplicate characters in key

**This is my code:**

```
    #include <cs50.h>

    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <ctype.h>

    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, string argv[])

   {
        string alphabet= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

if(argc != 2)
{
    printf("missing/more than 1 command-line argument\n");        
    return 1;
}

//check if there are 26 characters
int a= strlen(argv[1]);

if(a!=26)
{
    printf("key must contain 26 characters\n");
    return 1;
}


//Check if characters are all alphabetic
for(int i=0, n=strlen(argv[1]); i<n; i++)  
{
    if(!isalpha(argv[1][i])) 
    {
        printf("only alphabetic characters allowed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //check if each letter appear only once

    for(int j=1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if(argv[1][i]==argv[1][j])  
        {
            printf("repeated alphabets not allowed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        }
}


//prompt user for plaintext

string b= get_string("plaintext: \n");

int m=strlen(b);

char ciphertxt[m+1];   


//find out the alphabetical position of each character in string b (i.e character c in string b has alphabetical position of 3)

for(int k=0; k<m; k++)
{
    for(int p=0, q=strlen(alphabet); p<q; p++)
    {
        if(b[k]==alphabet[p])
        {
            ciphertxt[k]= tolower(argv[1][p]);

            break;                                
    }

    else if(b[k]==(alphabet[p]-32))
    {
        ciphertxt[k]= toupper(argv[1][p]);
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        ciphertxt[k]= b[k];
    }

}

    }

    ciphertxt[m]='\0';

    //print ciphertext

printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertxt);
return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you *run* your code using the tests cs50 shows you? I did; it does not encrypt anything; it always gives "*repeated alphabets not allowed*" message.

The problem is in the `j` loop. It will always report the 2nd letter of argv[1] as a duplicate. That is because `i` and `j` are both 1 therefore this `if(argv[1][i]==argv[1][j])`  always evaluates to *true*.

Comment: Thank you very much DinoCoderSaurus! It solved my issue! I just changed j=1 to j=i-1.

I tried running code using the tests CS50 shows before posting this question here. Realised it kept giving "repeated alphabets not allowed" message even though what I entered were all unique alphabets. Spend quite some time trying to figure out what was wrong but didnt spot the mistake in the j loop until you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

There are a several approaches to solving this problem. I will not solve them for you using the C programming language. You must do that yourself. Following is an approach that works very efficiently using the Ada programming language, but is not easily accomplished using the C programming language.

In Ada a string is defined as

```ada
type string is array (Positive range <>) of Character;
```

Thus, a string is an unconstrained array type, meaning instances of an array may be any length. Ada arrays require the programmer to define the range of values for the array index. Index values need not start at 0. Index values may start at any value which is valid for the type declared to be the index type. Index types may be integer types or enumeration types. Ada characters are an enumeration type, which allows the programmer to index an array using characters.

The following example uses many of the features described above.

```ada
with Ada.Command_Line;        use Ada.Command_Line;
with Ada.Text_IO;             use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Characters.Handling; use Ada.Characters.Handling;

procedure substitution is
   subtype lower is Character range 'a' .. 'z';
   subtype upper is Character range 'A' .. 'Z';
   subtype sequence is String (1 .. 26);
   alphabet : constant array (lower) of Positive :=
     (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
      21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26);

   function substitute (Char : Character; Key : sequence) return Character is
   begin
      if Char in lower then
         return To_Lower (Key (alphabet (To_Lower (Char))));
      elsif Char in upper then
         return To_Upper (Key (alphabet (To_Lower (Char))));
      else
         return Char;
      end if;
   end substitute;

   function is_duplicate (char : Character; Key : sequence) return Boolean is
      count : Natural := 0;
   begin
      for C of Key loop
         if C = char then
            count := count + 1;
         end if;
      end loop;
      return count > 1;
   end is_duplicate;

   Key : String (1 .. 26);

   Invalid_Argument_Error : exception;
begin
   if Argument_Count /= 1 then
      Put_Line ("There must be exactly one command line argument.");
      raise Invalid_Argument_Error;
   end if;

   if Argument (1)'Length /= 26 then
      Put_Line ("The argument must contain 26 characters.");
      raise Invalid_Argument_Error;
   else
      Key := Argument (1);
   end if;

   for C of Key loop
      if is_duplicate (C, Key) then
         Put_Line ("The argument cannot contain duplicate values.");
         raise Invalid_Argument_Error;
      end if;
   end loop;

   for C of Key loop
      if not (C in lower or else C in upper) then
         Put_Line ("The argument must contain only alphabetic characters.");
         raise Invalid_Argument_Error;
      end if;
   end loop;

   Put_Line ("Enter plain text:");
   declare
      input  : String := Get_Line;
      cipher : String (input'Range);
   begin
      for I in input'Range loop
         cipher (I) := substitute (input (I), Key);
      end loop;
      Put_Line ("cipher text: " & cipher);
   end;
end substitution;
```

Ada allows the starting procedure for a program to be named whatever the programmer wants to name it. In C the starting function must be named "main". In this example the starting procedure is named "substitution". Ada characters are full eight bit characters and represent the Latin-1 character set. The lower seven bits of the Latin-1 character set is the same as the ASCII character set. Thus, there are some lower case characters in the Latin-1 character set which are not part of the ASCII character set. For this reason the program defines the upper case characters and lower case characters unique to the ASCII character set by declaring two subtypes of the type character.

```ada
subtype lower is Character range 'a' .. 'z';
subtype upper is Character range 'A' .. 'Z';
```

The syntax 'a' .. 'z' defines a range of values and includes all the characters starting with 'a' and ending with 'z'.

A subtype of the Ada string type is named sequence and is declared to be a string indexed by the value range 1 .. 26. Thus, each instance of the subtype sequence must contain a 26 character string. Ada does not append a null character to the end of its strings.

The array named alphabet is defined to be a constant array indexed by the subtype lower. Each element of the array is an integer with a minimum value of 1. The array is initialized to the numbers 1 through 26 with 1 indexed by 'a' and 26 indexed by 'z'. This array is used as a look-up table for indexing into the key entered on the program command line.

The function named substitute takes two parameters; Char, which is a Character and Key which is a sequence (a 26 character string). Substitute returns the encrypted character value.

The function returns the character in the Key parameter indexed by the number which is indexed by the letter in the parameter Char. The array named alphabet becomes the look-up table for the index value corresponding to the character contained in the parameter Char.

The function named is_duplicate is used to determine if a character occurs more than once in a Key sequence. It simply counts the number of times the character in the Char parameter occurs in the Key sequence. The function returns TRUE if the count is greater than 1 and false if the count is not greater than 1.

After performing the necessary checks on the command-line parameter the program prompts for a string to encrypt and then simply assigns to the string cipher the encrypted character corresponding to each input character.